# Google Nearby Notifications Analytics

Tags: android, google-nearby

I have been working on nearby notifications. deployed n number of beacons in our work area. i have been trying to track the user analytics. I am able to track the click analytics of the url. I want to track the impressions for beacon campaigns.

I had done some research on finding analytics of notification reach in users device.there is no straightforward way to track the analytics.we have been getting log entries on PWS accessing the campaign url.but the access frequency is not accurate.

is there any to find the accurate user impression from the pws access logs or is there any other way to find the impressions.?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit old but I'll share what I have come to believe.  While testing using bit.ly addresses in the nearby url I get exactly 2 hits.  Not sure why 2 but it appears that google parses the url provided and caches the result.  If it's a redirect it will follow it and cache the resulting page thus eliminating the ability to track hits via middle redirect page.  If you use EURL (Physical web) then it never goes to Google first and you can track the hits via redirector like bit.ly.  There are advantages and disadvantages to both EURL and EUID.  I am quite certain google records each time a device requests the attachment data for a nearby but for some reason they chose not to give it to us.  I am not pleased that google does not expose that data to the owner.

Answer (score 1):

To be frank: No... you can't get accurate impressions.
Reason:
Google cache that beacon's URL + Message on their end for approx 3-5 minute even for different devices. 
As Google Nearby is in Beta phase, there are many bugs and important concept that are missed. And Impression count is one of them.